# Memory issues while running simple groupby statemtent in a big dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big dataframe of shape `(3125000, 16)`, when writing the code the dataset was quite small so had no problem in running the analysis using pandas. But now I have data frame as mentioned above and it is throwing me `'Memory error'` while running simple group by command. I'm at loss as the code is quite big and I can't rewrite the entire code again as the time is short and I have to give the output today to my client. Below are the two simple statements I'm running that are showing me a memory error.

```
####### Average 'A001' and 'A002' of each value of Symbol across the files
big_frame_grouped_A002 = big_frame.groupby('Symbol')['A002'].mean()
big_frame_grouped_A001 = big_frame.groupby('Symbol')['A001'].mean()
```

and

```
cnt = big_frame.groupby('Symbol').apply(lambda g:((g.A001 > g.A002) & g.A001.notnull() & g.A002.notnull()).sum())
```

I was able to read all the files in a data frame but it's not allowing me to do that anymore.
I tried searching online but have no idea how to take care of memory issues without rewriting the whole code.

I tried gc_collect method but it was of no use. Any help?

Edit: Dataset

```
  Symbol     Bid   BidQty     Ask   AskQty  TradeQty    iBid  iBidQty  \
0  O.U20  99.740  16011.0  99.745  71102.0     77361  99.740   1669.0   
1  O.Z20  99.695  30622.0  99.700  70102.0     72888  99.695   6803.0   
2  O.H21  99.795   4168.0  99.800  71275.0     66692     NaN      NaN   
3  O.M21  99.820  12254.0  99.825  45183.0     93346  99.820   4035.0   
4  O.U21  99.825  18379.0  99.830  33293.0     52012  99.825   4168.0   

   iBidLegs    iAsk  iAskQty  iAskLegs   RiskMid         filename   A001  \
0       2.0  99.745   6803.0       2.0  99.74092  63730342900.csv  0.005   
1       2.0  99.700     93.0       2.0  99.69717  63730342900.csv  0.005   
2       NaN  99.800  11902.0       2.0  99.79546  63730342900.csv  0.005   
3       2.0  99.825   3742.0       2.0  99.82069  63730342900.csv  0.005   
4       2.0  99.830   2361.0       2.0  99.82580  63730342900.csv  0.005   

    A002  
0  0.005  
1  0.005  
2    NaN  
3  0.005  
4  0.005
```

Comment: @Trenton really sorry for taking so much time in accepting the solution. In fact, this is the second time you have solved my problem (first one was related to matplotlib) and I am very thank full to you. Thanks and sorry again for the delay:)

Comment: I'm glad this solved your issue. Till next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Given the test data at the bottom in dataframe `df`, which is `(3125000, 16)`

  - I didn't experience any memory issues
  - Relative memory usage when running groupby functions

    - [image]
  - Did not come close to 16GB
  - For the original `cnt`: `851 ms ± 30.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
  - For the implementation below: `576 ms ± 5.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- Creating a groupby object of only the columns being used should reduce memory usage.
- Currently you're using `.apply`, which is essentially a `for-loop` to test every row
- Instead, use a `for-loop` to loop through each group of the `.groupby` object, then `.dropna`, and use `Boolean` indexing, which will get rid of iterating through each row.
- If you want `cnt` in a dataframe, use `cnt_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cnt, orient='index', columns=['counts'])`

```py
# groupby agg mean
dfg = df.groupby('Symbol').agg({'A001': 'mean', 'A002': 'mean'})

# display(dfg)
         A001   A002
Symbol              
O.H21   0.005    NaN
O.M21   0.005  0.005
O.U20   0.006  0.005
O.U21   0.007  0.005
O.Z20   0.004  0.005

# create a groupby object of only the columns being used
dfg_A = df[['Symbol', 'A001', 'A002']].groupby('Symbol')

# iterate through the groupby object
cnt = dict()
for g, f in dfg_A:
    f = f.dropna()  # drop any rows with Nan
    cnt_f = f[(f.A001 > f.A002)].count()
    cnt[g] = cnt_f.Symbol

print(cnt)
[out]: {'O.H21': 0, 'O.M21': 0, 'O.U20': 625000, 'O.U21': 625000, 'O.Z20': 0}
```

#### Test Data

```py
# copy the data to the clipboard and read in with
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')

# make it large
df = pd.concat([df] * 625000).reset_index(drop=True)

# data
   Symbol     Bid   BidQty     Ask   AskQty  TradeQty    iBid  iBidQty  iBidLegs    iAsk  iAskQty  iAskLegs   RiskMid         filename   A001   A002
0   O.U20  99.740  16011.0  99.745  71102.0     77361  99.740   1669.0       2.0  99.745   6803.0       2.0  99.74092  63730342900.csv  0.006  0.005
1   O.Z20  99.695  30622.0  99.700  70102.0     72888  99.695   6803.0       2.0  99.700     93.0       2.0  99.69717  63730342900.csv  0.004  0.005
2   O.H21  99.795   4168.0  99.800  71275.0     66692     NaN      NaN       NaN  99.800  11902.0       2.0  99.79546  63730342900.csv  0.005    NaN
3   O.M21  99.820  12254.0  99.825  45183.0     93346  99.820   4035.0       2.0  99.825   3742.0       2.0  99.82069  63730342900.csv  0.005  0.005
4   O.U21  99.825  18379.0  99.830  33293.0     52012  99.825   4168.0       2.0  99.830   2361.0       2.0  99.82580  63730342900.csv  0.007  0.005
```